# Mercurial: View pulled in content or file names after pull request

Tags: mercurial

I search the mercurial documentation but was not able to find anything similar to what I want to do:

After executing `hg pull`, it gives the summary for example:

```
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 5 changesets with 4 changes to 2 files
```

How can I few the names of the files that got change? and then change for each file? I also tried hg log but that was not really giving me the details that I was looking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of

```
hg incoming
```

(which displays the incoming changesets)

and

```
hg diff -c REVISION FILE
```

to get the changes for a file.

To see what exactly was changed in a file you can use

```
hg annotate -r REVISION -d -u FILE
```

which shows you exactly what was changed in a file by who.